# How to insert a blank line above my copyright text inside the comment lines in intelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, copyright-display

I'm using intelliJ IDEA 9.

It has a function to make a copyright profile and apply to all files I create.
What I'm trying to do is to format the copyright comment right.

Suppose I have a copyright text as this:
Copyright (c) 2010 my.company. All rights reserved.

I wish it to be inserted in files automatically as following:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Copyright (c) 2010 my.company. All rights reserved.
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

But when I enter the line "Copyright (c) 2010 my.company. All rights reserved." in the copyright profile (without quotes) and configure the formatting to use line comment and borders, and so on, I can only make it to display as below:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Copyright (c) 2010 my.company. All rights reserved.
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Even when I put the copyright text with blank line above and below to the template, as following, it still comes out like above.

```
    Copyright (c) 2010 my.company. All rights reserved.
```

It seems to ignore blank lines in the copyright template.
Is there any way to configure it so the copyright text will have blank lines above and below within the comments?

Comment: I believe IntelliJ uses Velocity internally for its templates, you might want to take a look at that documentation.

Comment: @sblundy: thanks for the tip. figured it out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Figured it out, after the tip from @sblundy.

```
#set($blankLine = '')
${blankLine}
Copyright (c) 2010 my.company. All rights reserved.
${blankLine}
```

Cool. Now it works.

Comment: is there any doc about IntelliJ IDEA macros?